# HAProxy add some headers before 302 redirect

Tags: redirect, header, addition, haproxy

I'm trying to add some security headers to the responses that are directed to a specific port.
I have the following configured frontend:

```
frontend desenv_ext_1 
bind *:80 
bind *:443  ssl crt /etc/ssl/certs/cert.pem 
mode http 
option tcplog 
default_backend desenv_1 
timeout client          5m

#ACL to new attempt 
acl header_c dst_port 80

#Attempt with no ACL 
http-response set-header X-Frame-Options SAMEORIGIN 

#Attempt with ssl ACL 
http-response set-header Strict-Transport-Security max-age=31535400;\ includeSubDomains;\ preload; if {ssl_fc} 
http-response add-header Referrer-Policy no-referrer if !{ ssl_fc }

#Attempt with header_c ACL 
http-response set-header X-Content-Type-Options nosniff if header_c 
http-response add-header X-XSS-Protection 1;\ mode=block if header_c

#Attempt with rspadd 
rspadd X-Backen-Serve\ laranja if header_c 
rspadd X-Backend-Serve\ caju if HTTP

redirect scheme https if !{ ssl_fc }
```

You see, in the configuration you have some tests in different ways, and neither of these ways works.

The redirect is working correctly, but the headers are not added in the port 80 response:

```
[root@managerr temp]# curl -I http://localhost
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Cache-Control: no-cache
Content-length: 0
Location: https://localhost/
Connection: close
```

I would like requests arriving on port 80 to have the following headers added, even if they have a redirect to port 443:

```
Strict-Transport-Security max-age=31535400;\ includeSubDomains;\ preload;
X-Frame-Options SAMEORIGIN
X-Content-Type-Options nosniff
X-XSS-Protection 1;\ mode=block
```

The output that I need is this:

```
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Strict-Transport-Security max-age=31535400;\ includeSubDomains;\ preload;
X-Frame-Options SAMEORIGIN
X-Content-Type-Options nosniff
X-XSS-Protection 1;\ mode=block
Cache-Control: no-cache
Content-length: 0
Location: https://localhost/
Connection: close
```

Backend:

```
backend desenv_1
mode http
option tcplog
server manga x.x.x.x:80 check cookie manga
timeout connect        10s
timeout server          5m
```

My HA-Proxy version 1.5.18

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`redirect` gets executed before `http-response`, so these `http-response` s never get executed.

use this:

```
http-request redirect location "https://%[hdr(host)]%[url]\r\nX-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN\r\nReferrer-Policy: no-referrer"
```

Comment: That's a clever hack, but will break clients connecting over HTTP/2, e.g. in cURL `http2 error: Invalid HTTP header field was received: frame type: 1, stream: 1, name: [location], value: [...] PROTOCOL_ERROR`. A more solid work-around is available here: [How to redirect with additional headers in the response?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56629877).