# How to redirect with additional headers in the response?

Tags: redirect, haproxy, cache-control

Currently, I use haproxy to upgrade some domains to https automatically to https. I use code 308 because I did not find a possibility to add a `Expires: Thu, 01 Dec 2014 16:00:00` or a `Cache-Control: max-age=3600` header.

```
frontend http-frontend
    bind *:80
    mode http
    redirect scheme https code 307 if { hdr(Host) -i foo.example.com } !{ ssl_fc }
    redirect scheme https code 307 if { hdr(Host) -i bar.example.com } !{ ssl_fc }
```

How do I have to modify above redirect rules to include a `Cache-Control` header in the response?

Answer (score 3):

HAProxy inserts headers in response with "http-request set-header" directive.
Unfortunately, at the time of writing, this is only available when HAProxy gets traffic from a backend.
"http-request redirect .." (or "redirect") is a final directive on a frontend there is no backend response in this case.
The  turnaround is to create a dummy backend like this:

```
frontend http-frontend
    bind *:80
    mode http
    use_backend be_dummy_redirect if { hdr(Host) -i foo.example.com } !{ ssl_fc }
    use_backend be_dummy_redirect if { hdr(Host) -i bar.example.com } !{ ssl_fc }
    default_backend be_app

 backend be_dummy_redirect
    http-response set-header Expires "Thu, 01 Dec 2014 16:00:00"
    http-response set-header Cache-Control max-age=3600
    server redirect-server 127.0.0.1:9000

 listen redirect
    bind 127.0.0.1:9000
    http-request redirect scheme https
```

This was [discussed](https://www.mail-archive.com/haproxy@formilux.org/msg25061.html) before with the Devs and maybe it is going to be implemented in the future

Comment: I will test this the day after tomorrow. But one comment I already have: Is the third layer really necessary? I.e. would it fail if I replace `server redirect-server 127.0.0.1:9000` with `http-request redirect scheme https`?

Comment: Yes because putting "http-request redirect" (or the legacy form "redirect") in the backend will be a final directive which means HAProxy won't send the request to the backend but directly answer with a redirect. Thus the "http-response" directives won't be processed.

Comment: Ah. final directive means basically that those are moved up in the execution line and execution terminates after the first final directive. Gotcha. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Has been resolved in haproxy 2.2

```
http-after-response set-header Cache-Control max-age=3600 if {condition}
```

https://github.com/haproxy/haproxy/issues/4#issuecomment-583335714

https://docs.haproxy.org/2.4/configuration.html#4.2-http-after-response%20set-header